# How to get path of picture in onActivityresult (Intent data is null)

Tags: android, android-intent, android-camera-intent

I have to launch the camera, and when the users has done the picture, I have to take it and show it in a view.

Looking at http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/media/camera.html I have done:

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        bLaunchCamera = (Button) findViewById(R.id.launchCamera);
        bLaunchCamera.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Log.d(TAG, "lanzando camara");

                //create intent to launch camera
                Intent intent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);

                imageUri = getOutputMediaFileUri(MEDIA_TYPE_IMAGE); //create a file to save the image
                intent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, imageUri); //set the image file name

                //start camera
                startActivityForResult(intent, CAMERA_REQUEST);
            }
        });

/**
     * Create a File Uri for saving image (can be sued to save video to)
     **/
    private Uri getOutputMediaFileUri(int mediaTypeImage) {
        return Uri.fromFile(getOutputMediaFile(mediaTypeImage));
    }

    /**
     * Create a File  for saving image (can be sued to save video to)
     **/
    private File getOutputMediaFile(int mediaType) {
        //To be safe, is necessary to check if SDCard is mounted

        File mediaStorageDir = new File(Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES),
                (String) getResources().getText(R.string.app_name));

        //create the storage directory if it does not exist
        if (!mediaStorageDir.exists()) {
            if (!mediaStorageDir.mkdirs()) {
                Log.d(TAG, "failed to create directory");
                return null;
            }
        }

        //Create a media file name

        String timeStamp = new SimpleDateFormat("ddMMyyyy_HHmmss").format(new Date());
        File mediaFile;

        if (mediaType == MEDIA_TYPE_IMAGE) {
            mediaFile = new File(mediaStorageDir.getPath() + File.separator + "IMG_" + timeStamp + ".jpg");

        } else {
            return null;
        }
        return mediaFile;
    }

@Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        if(requestCode == CAMERA_REQUEST) {
            if(resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
                //Image captured and saved to fileUri specified in Intent
                Toast.makeText(this, "image saved to:\n" + data.getData(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                Log.d(TAG, "lanzando camara");
            } else if(resultCode == RESULT_CANCELED) {
                //user cancelled the image capture;
                Log.d(TAG, "usuario a cancelado la captura");
            } else {
                //image capture failed, advise user;
                Log.d(TAG, "algo a fallado");
            }
        }
    }
```

When the picture has been done, the app crashes when it try to send the 'Toast' info because 'data' is null.

But if I debug the app I can see that the image has been saved.

[image]

So my question is: How can I get the path in the onActivityResult?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is code I have used for Capturing and Saving Camera Image then display it to imageview. You can use according to your need.

You have to save Camera image to specific location then fetch from that location then convert it to byte-array.

Here is method for opening capturing camera image activity.

```
private static final int CAMERA_PHOTO = 111;
private Uri imageToUploadUri;

private void captureCameraImage() {
        Intent chooserIntent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
        File f = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(), "POST_IMAGE.jpg");
        chooserIntent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, Uri.fromFile(f));
        imageToUploadUri = Uri.fromFile(f);
        startActivityForResult(chooserIntent, CAMERA_PHOTO);
    }

@Override
        protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
            super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

            if (requestCode == CAMERA_PHOTO && resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {
                if(imageToUploadUri != null){
                    Uri selectedImage = imageToUploadUri;
                    getContentResolver().notifyChange(selectedImage, null);
                    Bitmap reducedSizeBitmap = getBitmap(imageToUploadUri.getPath());
                    if(reducedSizeBitmap != null){
                        ImgPhoto.setImageBitmap(reducedSizeBitmap);
                        Button uploadImageButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.uploadUserImageButton);
                          uploadImageButton.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);                
                    }else{
                        Toast.makeText(this,"Error while capturing Image",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    }
                }else{
                    Toast.makeText(this,"Error while capturing Image",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }
            } 
        }
```

Here is getBitmap() method used in onActivityResult(). I have done all performance improvement that can be possible while getting camera capture image bitmap.

```
private Bitmap getBitmap(String path) {

        Uri uri = Uri.fromFile(new File(path));
        InputStream in = null;
        try {
            final int IMAGE_MAX_SIZE = 1200000; // 1.2MP
            in = getContentResolver().openInputStream(uri);

            // Decode image size
            BitmapFactory.Options o = new BitmapFactory.Options();
            o.inJustDecodeBounds = true;
            BitmapFactory.decodeStream(in, null, o);
            in.close();


            int scale = 1;
            while ((o.outWidth * o.outHeight) * (1 / Math.pow(scale, 2)) >
                    IMAGE_MAX_SIZE) {
                scale++;
            }
            Log.d("", "scale = " + scale + ", orig-width: " + o.outWidth + ", orig-height: " + o.outHeight);

            Bitmap b = null;
            in = getContentResolver().openInputStream(uri);
            if (scale > 1) {
                scale--;
                // scale to max possible inSampleSize that still yields an image
                // larger than target
                o = new BitmapFactory.Options();
                o.inSampleSize = scale;
                b = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(in, null, o);

                // resize to desired dimensions
                int height = b.getHeight();
                int width = b.getWidth();
                Log.d("", "1th scale operation dimenions - width: " + width + ", height: " + height);

                double y = Math.sqrt(IMAGE_MAX_SIZE
                        / (((double) width) / height));
                double x = (y / height) * width;

                Bitmap scaledBitmap = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(b, (int) x,
                        (int) y, true);
                b.recycle();
                b = scaledBitmap;

                System.gc();
            } else {
                b = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(in);
            }
            in.close();

            Log.d("", "bitmap size - width: " + b.getWidth() + ", height: " +
                    b.getHeight());
            return b;
        } catch (IOException e) {
            Log.e("", e.getMessage(), e);
            return null;
        }
    }
```

I hope it helps!

Comment: Yes! found the solution to my problem in this line --> if(imageToUploadUri != null){
                    Uri selectedImage = imageToUploadUri;  Thanks a lot!

Comment: received error : java.lang.SecurityException: Failed to find provider  for user 0; expected to find a valid ContentProvider for this authority

Answer (score 3):

The problem you are facing is that, whenever we select an image from camera intent, it may finish the activity which called it, so `imageUri` object you created will be null while you return.

so you need to save it when you exit the activity (to go to camera intent), like this -

```
    /**
     * Here we store the file url as it will be null after returning from camera
     * app
     */
    @Override
    protected void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
        super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);

        // save file url in bundle as it will be null on screen orientation
        // changes
        outState.putParcelable("file_uri", mImageUri);
    }
```

and retrieve it back when you come back to the activity -

```
    @Override
    protected void onRestoreInstanceState(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onRestoreInstanceState(savedInstanceState);

        // get the file url
        mImageUri = savedInstanceState.getParcelable("file_uri");
    }
```

Your code looks fine, you only need to add this change in it.