# Uri Returns null in onActivityResult

Tags: android, uri

I am doing a module which needs to convert image into pdf. i have successfully implemented the camera and can display its image. but my problem is getting the uri of that image. i saw a code snippet here in StackOverflow and followed it but it returns null.

here is my sample code:

```
            @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Intent cameraIntent = new Intent(android.provider.MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
            startActivityForResult(cameraIntent, CAMERA_REQUEST);
        }
    });
}

protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    if (requestCode == CAMERA_REQUEST && resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {
        Bitmap photo = (Bitmap) data.getExtras().get("data");
        imageView.setImageBitmap(photo);
        uri = data.getData();

        if(uri == null)
        {
            tvUri.setText("null");
        }else{
            tvUri.setText(uri.toString());
        }

    }
}
```

to test if it is null, i proceeded to set the textview into its value if it has one, but if not, then i set it to null.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32329461/how-to-get-path-of-picture-in-onactivityresult-intent-data-is-null

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/40844108/5324829

Comment: @quicklearner thanks, it worked.

Comment: i am glad it helped,mark my comment upvote so others can use it as well

Answer (score -1):

```
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent intent)
{
    Uri u = intent.getData();
}
```

Comment: this is what i did. still null

Comment: check it by adding breakpoints and debug then you will know data is available or not from intent.

Comment: **From review queue**: May I request you to please add some context around your source-code. Code-only answers are difficult to understand. It will help the asker and future readers both if you can add more information in your post.

Answer (score -1):

try this

```
uri = data.getExtras().get("data");
```

instead of

```
uri = data.getData();
```