# How to Take a picture and then read its Text using TextRecognizer

Tags: android, bitmap, decode

so i have this **button** to take a picture contains Text :

```
 takePic.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
     @Override
     public void onClick(View view) {

         Intent intent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
         startActivityForResult(intent,100);
     }
 });
```

then i get the image from the onActivityResult :

```
@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

    if(requestCode == 100) {
        Bitmap bitmap = (Bitmap) data.getExtras().get("data");

    }
}
```

**the problem now is when i pass this bitmap to textRecognizer detector i get no result**:

```
Bitmap bitmap = (Bitmap) data.getExtras().get("data");
Frame frame = new Frame.Builder().setBitmap(bitmap).build();
textRecognizer = new TextRecognizer.Builder(this).build();

SparseArray<TextBlock> item = textRecognizer.detect(frame);
```

**if the image was stored in drawable folder** i can easily do this:

```
Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(),R.drawable.myImage);
```

and i'm good to go with TextRecognizer ..

but i can't figure out how to deal with an image taken by the camera.

**EDIT :**

full example:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {


    private TextRecognizer textRecognizer;
    private ImageView imageView;
    private TextView Result;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        imageView = findViewById(R.id.imageView);
        Result = findViewById(R.id.tvResult);
        Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(),R.drawable.image);

        Frame frame = new Frame.Builder().setBitmap(bitmap).build();
        textRecognizer = new TextRecognizer.Builder(this).build();

        SparseArray<TextBlock> item = textRecognizer.detect(frame);

        StringBuilder stringBuilder = new StringBuilder();

        for (int i=0; i<item.size(); i++){

            stringBuilder.append(item.valueAt(i).getValue());


        } 
   Result.setText(stringBuilder.toString());

    }

}
```

activity_main.xml:

```
 <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:srcCompat="@drawable/image" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tvResult"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginBottom="96dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:text="result"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent" />
```

Comment: when i use that bitmap from the request  with textRecognizer, it returns null

Comment: `now i want to decode this image using BitmapFactory` ??? What do you mean with 'this image'? You have already a bitmap. There is nothing else.  And whatever you would let BitmapFactory decode you would get a bitmap too.

Comment: i didn't use proper words to explain my point so i put an example that works perfectly with images from drawable.

Comment: Your example does not explain what you want or need. You should start writing a better post and question.

Comment: You can use the bitmap you obtained from the camera in `Frame frame = new Frame.Builder().setBitmap(bitmap).build();` too. What is the problem doing so?

Comment: the problem is when i do that , i get no result from TextRec detector.

Comment: Well why cannot i read that in your post? And second why do you think you would get a result if you could use bitmap factory?

Comment: It would also have been nice if you had started your post telling that you use the camera to take a picture of a text. And that you want to decode a text. OCR.

Comment: ok i just updated my post again , for some reason i thougt the main problem was with the bitmapFactory , anyway thanks for your time and questions

Comment: You still do not start your post telling that you take a picture of a text.

Comment: `i thougt the main problem was with the bitmapFactory , `. Nonsense. You are not using that. So how could it?

Comment: You have two bitmaps. Both contain text i presume. One text is readable at ocr and the other not. So why can one bitmap not be used? Display both in an ImageView and compare. Then you will realise the difference.

Comment: have you tried yourself to make this work? without using picture from the drawable! i mean taking a picture then read it with ocr

Comment: Yes i know exactly what is going on and why you cant use that bitmap. Im trying to let you realise and formulate your problem.

Comment: The funny thing here is that indeed to solve your problem BitmapFactory has to be used. And code to do so you can read in the answers. But. Why that bitmap is not usable and why answer would work has not been explained yet. Moreover the answers are not complete.

Comment: And no. I have not used ocr. But the reason your bitmap from the camera is not usable is obvious. The reason has been published a hundred times here on stackoverflow.

Comment: then keep your secret answer for yourself

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's better to give a file to the camera intent, so It saves the file for you.

According to [This Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32329569/450356):

```
private static final int CAMERA_PHOTO = 111;
private Uri imageToUploadUri;

private void captureCameraImage() {
        Intent chooserIntent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
        File f = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(), "POST_IMAGE.jpg");
        chooserIntent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, Uri.fromFile(f));
        imageToUploadUri = Uri.fromFile(f);
        startActivityForResult(chooserIntent, CAMERA_PHOTO);
    }

@Override
        protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
            super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

            if (requestCode == CAMERA_PHOTO && resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {
                if(imageToUploadUri != null){
                    Uri selectedImage = imageToUploadUri;
                    getContentResolver().notifyChange(selectedImage, null);
                    Bitmap reducedSizeBitmap = getBitmap(imageToUploadUri.getPath());
                    if(reducedSizeBitmap != null){
                        ImgPhoto.setImageBitmap(reducedSizeBitmap);
                        Button uploadImageButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.uploadUserImageButton);
                          uploadImageButton.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);                
                    }else{
                        Toast.makeText(this,"Error while capturing Image",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    }
                }else{
                    Toast.makeText(this,"Error while capturing Image",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }
            } 
        }

private Bitmap getBitmap(String path) {

        Uri uri = Uri.fromFile(new File(path));
        InputStream in = null;
        try {
            final int IMAGE_MAX_SIZE = 1200000; // 1.2MP
            in = getContentResolver().openInputStream(uri);

            // Decode image size
            BitmapFactory.Options o = new BitmapFactory.Options();
            o.inJustDecodeBounds = true;
            BitmapFactory.decodeStream(in, null, o);
            in.close();


            int scale = 1;
            while ((o.outWidth * o.outHeight) * (1 / Math.pow(scale, 2)) >
                    IMAGE_MAX_SIZE) {
                scale++;
            }
            Log.d("", "scale = " + scale + ", orig-width: " + o.outWidth + ", orig-height: " + o.outHeight);

            Bitmap b = null;
            in = getContentResolver().openInputStream(uri);
            if (scale > 1) {
                scale--;
                // scale to max possible inSampleSize that still yields an image
                // larger than target
                o = new BitmapFactory.Options();
                o.inSampleSize = scale;
                b = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(in, null, o);

                // resize to desired dimensions
                int height = b.getHeight();
                int width = b.getWidth();
                Log.d("", "1th scale operation dimenions - width: " + width + ", height: " + height);

                double y = Math.sqrt(IMAGE_MAX_SIZE
                        / (((double) width) / height));
                double x = (y / height) * width;

                Bitmap scaledBitmap = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(b, (int) x,
                        (int) y, true);
                b.recycle();
                b = scaledBitmap;

                System.gc();
            } else {
                b = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(in);
            }
            in.close();

            Log.d("", "bitmap size - width: " + b.getWidth() + ", height: " +
                    b.getHeight());
            return b;
        } catch (IOException e) {
            Log.e("", e.getMessage(), e);
            return null;
        }
    }
```

Comment: I'm a beginner but i'll try to understand this and i hope you know what i'm trying to do

Comment: You pass a file (a URI) to the camera intent, when the user takes the picture, the camera activity takes care of saving the image in the file. now in `onActivityResult` you read the bytes, and convert it into a bitmap.

Comment: this was the best answer that solved my problem, thank you!

Comment: No problem! Glad you got it.

Comment: it will be nice if you help me to create a fullscreen surfaceView https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49653139/how-to-create-a-fullscreen-preview-with-camerasource-and-surfaceview

Answer (score 0):

First you can convert bitmap to **byte array** like that

```
 ByteArrayOutputStream outputStream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
 bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, outputStream);
 byte[] byteArray = outputStream.toByteArray();
```

After that you can use BitmapFactory' s decodeByteArray() function with option

```
BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(byteArray , 0 ,byteArray.length,*option)
```

*option is your bitmap factory option

Answer (score 0):

That is one of the simplest ways to get `Bitmap` from taken image by using `InputStream` and `BitmapFactory`.

```
@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    InputStream stream;
    if (requestCode == 100 && resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {
        try {
            stream = getContentResolver().openInputStream(data.getData());
            Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(stream);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: looks good and easy but still getting null when i try to use the bitmap with TextRecognizer

Comment: That's strange because that works for me (without `TextRecognizer`). Could it be something else null not `Bitmap`? It will be better that you would show your code where you getting `Bitmap` and where/how you using it

Comment: i know it's confusing , i will update my question with full example to show you how i use it with TextRec. it works perfectly if the image were in drawable folder.

Comment: @LovingAndroid On which of these lines you're getting a null pointer exception?

Comment: not your code , just the TextRec detector doesn't read anything and returns null when i pass the bitmap to it.

Comment: i think i found the issue , probably because the image becomes very small when i get it from onActivityResult

Comment: Try to use `Bitmap bigBitmap = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(bitmap, bitmap.getWidth()*2, bitmap.getHeight()*2, true);` to resize your `Bitmap` to bigger. @LovingAndroid

Comment: good idea, but it looks like a 400 years old pic lol , me myself can't read it :)

Comment: Have you tried with other picture? Maybe it's because of the picture. :D

Comment: i did and still the same :( , but i found a way to get rid of this issue , by getting the file name and path of the pic and view it

Comment: but i can't change the orientation to portrait when i view it