# Take and save photo to network folder Android

Tags: java, android, smb, jcifs

I spend +50h in this and I cant find a solution, need some help.
I'm trying to take a photo and save it on NAS folder.
I actually can connect to NAS from Android and create a folder but cant get the photo from camera to copy it on NAS.

Method to open the camera.

```
private void dispatchTakePictureIntent() {
    Intent takePictureIntent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
    // Ensure that there's a camera activity to handle the intent
    if (takePictureIntent.resolveActivity(getApplication().getPackageManager()) != null) {
        // Create the File where the photo should go
        File photoFile = null;

        try {
            photoFile = createImageFile();

            if (photoFile != null) {

                 photoURI = FileProvider.getUriForFile(getApplicationContext(),
                        "p.cristian.sealed.provider",
                        photoFile);

                 deleteFile(photoFile.getName());

               takePictureIntent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, photoURI);
               // takePictureIntent.putExtra("picname", photoURI);
                startActivityForResult(takePictureIntent, REQUEST_TAKE_PHOTO);
                photoFile.deleteOnExit();
            }
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            Log.e("ERROR", ex.getMessage());
        }
    }
}


private File createImageFile() throws IOException {
    String imageFileName = "IMG";
    File storageDir = 
    getApplication().getExternalFilesDir(Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES);
    File image = null;
    
    image = File.createTempFile(
            imageFileName,
            ".jpg",
            storageDir
    );
    
    currentPhotoPath = image.getAbsolutePath();

    return image;
}

private void algo(String nombreCarpetaNueva, String rutaImagenACopiar){

    SmbFileOutputStream out = null;
    try {
        NtlmPasswordAuthenticator auth = new NtlmPasswordAuthenticator("MyDomain", 
        "MyUser", "MyPass");
        SmbFile smbFile = new SmbFile("smb://" + auth.getUserDomain() + ";" + 
auth.getUsername() + ":" + auth.getPassword() + "@" + "192.168.1.50/NAS/Software/" + 
nombreCarpetaNueva);

        if (!smbFile.exists()) {
            smbFile.mkdirs();
        }

        smbFile.connect();

        SmbFile nuevoArchivo = new SmbFile(smbFile + "/" + rutaImagenACopiar);

        int cursor;

        jcifs.smb1.smb1.SmbFileInputStream in = new 
jcifs.smb1.smb1.SmbFileInputStream(nuevoArchivo);
        out = new SmbFileOutputStream(nuevoArchivo);

        while ((cursor = in.read()) != -1) {
            out.write(cursor);
        }

        out.flush();
        out.close();
    }
    catch (Exception e) {

        String msg = "ERROR: " + e.getLocalizedMessage();
        Log.i("asdf:",msg);
    }

}

@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, @Nullable Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

    if (requestCode == REQUEST_IMAGE_CAPTURE && resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
        Bundle extras = data.getExtras(); // ALWAYS NULL
        String fileName = extras.getString("picname"); //NOT WORKING IS NULL

        algo("R_folder", fileName); //this just create the folder but never copy the image.
       //algo("R_folder", fileName+".jpg");           
    }
}
```

MANIFEST

```
 <uses-permission
        android:name="android.permission.AUTHENTICATE_ACCOUNTS"
        android:maxSdkVersion="22" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.GET_ACCOUNTS"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.USE_CREDENTIALS"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.MANAGE_ACCOUNTS"/>

    <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera" android:required="true" />
    <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera.autofocus" />
...
    <provider
            android:name="androidx.core.content.FileProvider"
            android:authorities="p.cristian.sealed.provider"
            android:exported="false"
            android:grantUriPermissions="true">
            <meta-data
                android:name="android.support.FILE_PROVIDER_PATHS"
                android:resource="@xml/file_paths" />
    </provider>
```

FILE_PATHS FILE

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <paths xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <external-files-path name="my_images" path="/" />
    </paths>
```

I tested a lot of stackoverflow answers but never got the correct one in my case :(
Some site answers tested from:

[Android Camera Intent: how to get full sized photo?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6448856/android-camera-intent-how-to-get-full-sized-photo)

[Get file path of image on Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15432592/get-file-path-of-image-on-android)

[How to get path of picture in onActivityresult (Intent data is null)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32329461/how-to-get-path-of-picture-in-onactivityresult-intent-data-is-null)

Android doc, and much more sites..

**EDIT - GOT THE SOLUTION**

```
private void algo(String rutaImagenACopiar){

    SmbFileOutputStream out = null;
    try {
        NtlmPasswordAuthenticator auth = new NtlmPasswordAuthenticator("MyDomain", "myUser", "MyPass");

        File file = new File(rutaImagenACopiar);
        String fileName = file.getName();
        SmbFile smbFile = new SmbFile("smb://" + auth.getUserDomain() + ";" + auth.getUsername() + ":" + auth.getPassword() + "@" + "192.168.1.50/NAS/Software/" + fileName);

        if (!smbFile.exists()) {
            smbFile.createNewFile();
           //smbFile.mkdirs();
        }
        smbFile.connect();

        InputStream inNew = new FileInputStream(file);
        SmbFileOutputStream outNew = new SmbFileOutputStream(smbFile);

        byte[] buf = new byte[8192];
        int len;
        while ((len = inNew.read(buf)) > 0) {
            outNew.write(buf, 0, len);
        }
        inNew.close();
        outNew.close();
}
```

Now I just need to get the correct buffer size

Comment: You appear to be trying to copy the NAS file to itself. `in` probably should not be defined via `jcifs.smb1.smb1.SmbFileInputStream in = new 
jcifs.smb1.smb1.SmbFileInputStream(nuevoArchivo);`.

Comment: `algo("R_folder", fileName); ` You cannot extract file name/path from intent extras. You mean: `algo("R_folder", currentPhotoPath);` (If you find that variable to be null then you should have saved the value in onSaveInstanceState()).

Comment: `photoFile = createImageFile();` AND `deleteFile(photoFile.getName());` ??? It makes little sense first to create a file and then to delete it. The only thing you need is a FIle instance.

Comment: So @CommonsWare what I should do? 

SmbFile nuevoArchivo = new SmbFile(rutaImagenACopiar);
InputStream in = nuevoArchivo.getInputStream();

// SmbFileInputStream in = new SmbFileInputStream(nuevoArchivo);
out = new SmbFileOutputStream(smbFile);

This throw a MalformedURLException
java.net.MalformedURLException: no protocol: /storage/emulated/0/Android/data/p.cristian.sealed/files/Pictures/IMG913230588666294152.jpg

Comment: My guess is that `in` should be a `FileInputStream` for the file that you created in `createNewFile()`. If the SMB file is your output, it cannot also be your input.

Comment: @CommonsWare YES! You are right, thanks a lot Sir.
The problem was that I just create a folder but not a file, so my inputStream was always null when it try to get the file path from NAS. Thanks again!