# Saving Byte Array as a PNG file into smb2 server

Tags: java, android-studio, jcifs

I'm trying to create an app that will save image from a Byte[] Array as a .png file into my smb2 server, I was able to save a file but it only contains the Array as file name with 0kb size.

**Getting image from camera**

```
@SuppressLint("MissingSuperCall")
    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, @Nullable Intent data) {
        if(requestCode == REQUEST_CODE) {
            if (resultCode != RESULT_CANCELED) {
                image = (Bitmap) data.getExtras().get("data");
                ByteArrayOutputStream byteArrayOutputStream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
                image.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, byteArrayOutputStream);
                bytesCapturedLogbook = byteArrayOutputStream.toByteArray();

                MyCopy my = new MyCopy();
                my.execute(bytesCapturedLogbook);
            }
        }
    }
```

**Class for inserting file into my server**

```
private class MyCopy extends AsyncTask<byte[], String, String> {

        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(byte[]... bytes) {
            String z = "";
            try {

                String url = "smb://000.000.0.000/spm/Image/" + bytes + ".png";

                NtlmPasswordAuthentication auth = new NtlmPasswordAuthentication(
                        null, "********", "**********");
                SmbFile sfile = new SmbFile(url, auth);

                if (!sfile.exists()) {
                    sfile.createNewFile();
                    z = "Created the file for you!!!!";
                } else
                    z = "Already exists at the specified location!!!!";

            } catch (Exception ex) {
                // TODO: handle exception
                z = ex.getMessage().toString();
            }
            return z;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub


        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(String r) {
        }


    }
```

**Result inside file explorer**

[image]

Comment: I don't see anywhere that you actually attempt to write any bytes to file. See here for how this could be done: [byte\[\] to file in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4350084/byte-to-file-in-java) or see [this answer using newer NIO features](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29623982/1270000)

Comment: There's no file getting saved, when I tried all the answers from the link you provided.

Comment: doInBackground: java.io.FileNotFoundException: 004920224616080824: open failed: EROFS (Read-only file system)

004920224616080824 is the file name

Comment: It would help if you updated the question with the actions that save the `bytes` parameter of `doBackground`. At present this creates empty file. By the way the parameter is defined as `byte[][]` due to the `...`.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71394187/take-and-save-photo-to-network-folder-android, I updated my code like this, but I get  'java.io.FileNotFoundException'

Comment: Unfortunately we can't guess which bits of the other question you've copied. I've voted to close (needs debugging details) because your program seems to work exactly as you've described: it intentionally creates an empty file.

Comment: I'm only a beginner, I really don't know what I supposed to do, hoping someone can help me.

Comment: @Ryan Baltazar I've added suggestions in an answer below which may help, though this question may get closed soon. BTW You've used `bytes + ".png"` as the target file which means you have a weird filename `[[B...`.